# Target input type in scss

Tags: sass

I have this code in scss. Is there some way, how to target input type more efficiently?

```
  &__form {
    input {
      display:block;
    }
    [type="number"] {display:block;}
    [type="date"] {display:block;}
    [type="name"] {display:block;}
  }
```

for example something like this (but it doesn't work)

```
  &__form {
    input {
      display:block;
    }

    [type] {
      "number" {display:block}
      "name" {display:block}
      "date" {display:block}
    }
  }
```

EDIT: `display:block` is not important here, it is only some dummy data

Comment: I assume you want to be able to apply different styles to each input type? If so, I think your current approach is good. If you want to apply `display:block` to every input type, though, you could loop through a [Sass list](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists) of types.

Comment: ```display:block``` is just dummy code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're shooting for but I'm guessing something like;

```
$inputs: number, date, name;

@each $input in $inputs{
  [type=#{$input}] {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
  &[type='number'] {
    display: block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can comma-separate selectors before starting your rules block:

```scss
.foo {
  &__form {
    input {
      display: block;
    }
    [type="number"],
    [type="date"],
    [type="name"] {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding the compiled output, that is what SCSS would also do with your code:

```
.foo__form input {
  display: block;
}

.foo__form [type="number"],
.foo__form [type="date"],
.foo__form [type="name"] {
  display: block;
}
```